# NullPointerException accessing entity by ID when @CreatedBy auditing is used

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I just added a relation with @CreatedBy to one of my entites and since then, I receive a NullPointerException accessing it via ID. But first things first:

The entity. I am leaving out some fields but left the "owner" in place, since the stack trace (see below) refers to that. The "creator" is the relation I added.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Invitation implements BaseEntity<Long>, OwnedEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Company owner;

    @CreatedBy
    @OneToOne
    private Account creator;

    ...
}
```

The "creator" field is set by my implementation of AuditorAware which looks like this:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class AuditorProvider implements AuditorAware<Account> {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(AuditorProvider.class);

    private final @NonNull AccountRepo accountRepo;

    @Override
    public Optional<Account> getCurrentAuditor() {
        Optional<Account> opt = accountRepo.findMe();
        if (opt.isPresent()) {
            LOG.debug("Found auditor: " + opt.get());   
        } else {
            LOG.debug("No auditor found."); 
        }
        return opt;
    }

}
```

The method accountRepo.findMe() finds the current instance of Account based on the security context.

With this in place, when I POST an Invitation entity like

```
curl -XPOST -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-type: application/hal+json" localhost:8081/invitations -d '{"email":"k@lo.de","role":"http://localhost:8081/roles/139"}'
```

the response body looks good:

```
{
  "email" : "k@lo.de",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/invitations/144"
    },
    "invitation" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/invitations/144"
    },
    "creator" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/invitations/144/creator"
    },
    "role" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/invitations/144/role"
    },
    "owner" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/invitations/144/owner"
    }
  }
}
```

The database table for Invitations and the logs show that the "creator" has successfully been set.

Fetching all invitations works perfectly fine without any errors:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-type: application/hal+json" http://localhost:8081/invitations
```

Fetching that Invitation with ID 144 gives me an HTTP 500 error:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-type: application/hal+json" http://localhost:8081/invitations/144
```

Looking into the logs, I see this stack trace: https://pastebin.com/mVzHHddU

The reason I left the "owner" relation in the snippet above is this line:

```
at training.edit.identity.model.Company.hashCode(Company.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
```

Other than that, none of the lines are familiar to me and I cannot make any sense out of the error.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

**Edit: The company entity**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Company implements BaseEntity<Long>, OwnedEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

    public boolean addAddress(Address address) {
        return this.addresses.add(address);
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public ScopedEntity getParent() {
        return null;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public Set<Company> getTenants() {
        return Sets.newHashSet(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTenant(Company tenant) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot configure tenant on Company.");
    }


}
```

**Edit:** Because of the lombok related comment below, I removed the @Data annotation from Company and created the getters and setters manually. Like this, fetching an Invitation by ID works.

Does that make sense to anyone?

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Company` entity? Since the error happens in the `hashCode` method generated by Lombok, it would be good to [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok) the class and look at the generated code.

Comment: I added that code above. How can that be related to adding that "creator" relation? As soon as I remove that relation, everything works fine